# Hadoop: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, putty

So I am brand new to Hadoop and the command line although I have done some programming before (as a student). I am trying to run a few simple programs (part of a tutorial) from  Putty on the school machine.

I have gotten Hadoop commands to work before and run a different simple program just fine but I am stuck with this one. 
No, this is not homework. Just a tutorial to get to know the Hadoop commands.

Instructions say the following:

/*

Testing the Code

We perform local testing conforming to typical UNIX-style piping, our testing will take the form:

cat  | map | sort | reduce
Which emulates the same pipeline that Hadoop will perform when streaming, albeit in a non-distributed manner. You have to make sure that files mapper.py and reducer.py have execution permissions:

chmod u+x mapper.py
chmod u+x reducer.py

Try the following command and explain the results (hint: type man sort in your terminal window to find out more about the sort command):

echo "this is a test and this should count the number of words" | ./mapper.py | sort -k1,1 | ./reducer.py

*/

Running  "hdfs dfs -ls /user/$USER gives the following result:

Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x   - s1353460 s1353460          0 2015-10-20 10:51 /user/s1353460/QuasiMonteCarlo_1445334654365_163883167
drwxr-xr-x   - s1353460 s1353460          0 2015-10-20 10:51 /user/s1353460/data
-rw-r--r--   3 s1353460 s1353460        360 2015-10-20 12:13 /user/s1353460/mapper.py
-rw-r--r--   3 s1353460 s1353460      15346 2015-10-20 11:11 /user/s1353460/part-r-00000
-rw-r--r--   2 s1353460 s1353460        728 2015-10-21 10:21 /user/s1353460/reducer.py
drwxr-xr-x   - s1353460 s1353460          0 2015-10-16 14:38 /user/s1353460/source

But running "echo "this is a test and this should count the number of words" | /user/$USER/mapper.py | sort -k1,1 | /user/$USER/reducer.py" returns errors:

-bash: /user/s1353460/reducer.py: No such file or directory
-bash: /user/s1353460/mapper.py: No such file or directory

which seems odd since just above the were listed exactly with in that position.
Any idea of what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, using echo, you are testing your files locally and not touching HDFS at all. HDFS is a file system abstraction... but that's another topic.

If mapper.py or reducer.py are not in your current directory, you'll have your mentioned problem regardless if they are in HDFS at the same path.

To use your local python files with hadoop streaming, you need to use the streaming jar (its location depends on your installation) see [this post here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/).

Answer (score 1):

> But running "echo "this is a test and this should count the number of words" | /user/$USER/mapper.py | sort -k1,1 | /user/$USER/reducer.py" returns errors:
>
> -bash: /user/s1353460/reducer.py: No such file or directory -bash: /user/s1353460/mapper.py: No such file or directory

You have created **`mapper.py`** & **`reducer.py`** on **HDFS**. When you run this command, it searches **`mapper.py`** and **`reducer.py`** on your local file system not on **`HDFS`**.

To fix this issue:

1. Ensure /user/s1353460/ exist on **`your local file system`**. if it doesn't, create the same and then copy or create **`mapper.py`** & **`reducer.py`** in /user/s1353460/
2. Make sure the **`mapper.py`** has execution permission **`chmod +x /user/s1353460/mapper.py`**
3. Make sure the **`reducer.py`** has execution permission **`chmod +x /user/s1353460/reducer.py`**
4. Run **`echo "this is a test and this should count the number of words" | /user/s1353460/mapper.py | sort -k1,1 | /user/s1353460/reducer.py`** It should work this time without any error.

**To run Python MapReduce job on the Hadoop cluster:**

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar \
-file /user/s1353460/mapper.py    -mapper /user/s1353460/mapper.py \
-file /user/s1353460/reducer.py   -reducer /user/s1353460/reducer.py \
-input <hdfs-input-path> -output <hdfs-output-path>
```

**Assumption:** **`Hadoop`** is installed in **`/usr/local/hadoop`**. Change the path appropriately.

Comment: Your step 4 still does not run on HDFS, all your other steps are good, though. To actually run on HDFS, you must use the Hadoop streaming jar with the - files parameter.

Comment: Author of the original problem is trying to test it locally and the command is failing

Comment: Ah, my bad, read step 1 as create that directory in HDFS,  because I've ran into the issue where the local username's user folder does not exist in HDFS and a similar error occurs.